# Auto generated connection string of (localDB)\mssqllocalDB is not working in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have created the new ADO.net entity object & pointed to `(localDB)\mssqllocaldb` (the connection string created automatically, table name `tblProduct`). After adding new controller (e.g. `Product`) with this entity and trying to access the index page, I'm getting an error.

Note : I am able to connect to the database  in SQL Server Management Studio and also able to see the database in DataConnections in the Visual Studio server explorer

Error :

> Exception message: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Cannot get a local application data path. Most
>   probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under
>   IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user. )

Application log in Windows Log:

> Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not >loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is >enabled for the current user.

Connection string

> add name="productsContextV12" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.products.csdl|res:‌​//*/Models.products.‌​ssdl|res://*/Models.‌​products.msl;provide‌​r=System.Data.SqlCli‌​ent;provider connection string="data source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=EMPDB2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramew‌​ork"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: can you show us the connectionstring that is not working ?

Comment: <add name="productsContextV12" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.products.csdl|res://*/Models.products.ssdl|res://*/Models.products.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=EMPDB2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>

Comment: Can you edit our question and put the connectionstring there so it is readable ? Comments are not reader friendly for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue got resolved after replacing "DataResouce=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb" with "Server=np:\.\pipe\LOCALDB#2XXXX\tsql\query" in ConnectionString .

Server name holds instance pipe name ,this can be found using command :

c:> sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb . below is the image  for details .

Thanks to GuidoG for ur quick response

command for the instance details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionstring is for LocalDB but the file is not set in the connectionstring. In stead it looks like you set the 'initial catalog' property to a database in some sql server.

For localDb you have to set the file containing the database, usually this is an MDF file.

This is what you need to do :

Create a textfile anywhere on your disk, and give it extension .udl
Now doubleclick on this file, the Microsoft datalink properties window will now open.
In this window configure everything until a click on 'test connection' succeeds.
Remember to choose

> Attach a database file as a database name:

When this is done and 'test connection' returned success, then open the file in notepad and examen how the correct connectionstring should be in your case.